# How to fix 'lua: cannot open script: no such file or directory' error

Tags: lua

I'm trying to run 'lua script a b c' from command line on Windows 10, but it returns the error 'lua: cannot open script: no such file or directory' error.

I was learning lua from http://www.lua.org/pil/1.4.html and it said that it would create some kind of a table if I did this, but it returns an error.

I've tried to put in the name of an actual lua script with variables a, b and c instead of 'script', but then just nothing happens.

Comment: Do you have file `script` in the current directory?  You can check it with `dir /b`.  Probably, your file's name is `script.lua` instead of `script`?

Comment: I'm not trying to open an actual lua script, but to follow the instructions on http://www.lua.org/pil/1.4.html . It should act similarly to -i, -l and -e, but it returns an error once I run it. It should create some kind of table I think.

Comment: The line `prompt> lua script a b c` assumes that you have created a file named `script` and have written your program into it.

Comment: When I use an actual lua script instead of just  'script' it just runs the script without making a table like it says it should.

Comment: Show your actual script which doesn't see the table `arg`

Comment: I used a script in which I just assigned values to variables a, b and c. Do I have to do something else? It just executes the script once I run the command and doesn't make a table.

Comment: One [picture](https://imgur.com/a/gRirdrU) would be better than thousand words

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. So I can't just print out the arg table, but it really was made and does exist!

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure full path script, full path is required every time the file is not in the current directory.